# I enter my domain URL into the address bar of iOS Safari but it searches instead of going to the domain address

Tags: url, mobile-safari

I have a website `sparkles.site` installed into a multisite WordPress site. When I navigate to it on the desktop it opens the webpage correctly, however if I enter the URL into Safari on the iPhone I am getting Google search results.

If I add a trailing slash (i.e. `sparkles.site/`), it then navigates to the website correctly.

Is there a way of setting this up so that both options would work?

Comment: what is the url of your site, is it `sparkles.site` ?

Comment: I think the issue is that Safari doesn't recognise your domain as a valid url domain, so the solution would be to find out the stored recognised values that Safari uses and adding your website doman shape (such as `.site`) to the accepted values.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and it is horrendously annoying. I know the URL is valid because it is that of an image on a valid page but for some reason, Safari refuses to go there and displays search results instead.
There has to be a way to disable this nonsense, when it sees a URL it should go there, not search.
Note that this happens to me on a Mac (Mojave).